# Firebase deep increment of a field in a data base

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have this structure:
`Users` is a `collection`, inside there are `userIDs` docs, each has a `user` object which contains also an object with a certain nick name .

```
  Users          //collection
      userID-xx. //document
        user     //object
            analytics{
               nick1{
                 visitors:4
                }
               nick2{
                 visitors:8
                }
           }

      userID-yy
      ....
```

I would like to **increment** `visitors` for `userID-XX` for **nick2**. Done from my **function**.

I know only how to get till here..

```
       var docRef = admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(userAuthID);
        docRef.update({ `user.analytics.${nickID}.visitors`: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });
```

which gives warning. ( Unexpected template string expression  )

and add to my object a new field  `${nickID}`

How can i update  the specific object by `nick2` with this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved

```
docRef.update({ ['user.analytics.' + nickID + '.visitors']: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });
```